# Sencha Touch 2 CSS not working

Tags: css, sencha-touch, sass, sencha-touch-2, compass-sass

When creating a new CSS theme and after compiling the theme with compass, there was no change on the styles. Everything was looking just like before, with the default theme. How to solve this ?

Comment: please be more specific, since your problem is very weird

Comment: I posted this in a simple maner because I wanted to answer it also in a simple maner. I don't know if it was because of a previous tutorial  but something made me put the link to the css file above the script that includes Sencha Touch SDK. Also, the fact that for instance including pictos worked fine didn't help understand what was going on. There should be a note somewhere on the docs or tutorial to make sure you include the css after the JS.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you move the link to your CSS file below the line:

```
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>
```

I put it right at the end of the `<head></head>` element.

```
(...)
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default-theme.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
</head>
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place all your variables below the default @import statements like this:

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

$base-color: #27ae60;
$base-gradient: 'matte';
$alert-color: #2ecc71;
$confirm-color: #e67e22;
$page-bg-color: #3498db;
$form-bg-color: #ecf0f1;
$button-radius: '0px';
```